# I have an error about vue2.js and its router

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, routes, frontend, vue-router

I have a navbar,Home and login elements. It is simple login page. I want to add api to go home and login page. For this i have router.js file. I am sharing all of file here.

This is my Main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import useRoute from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  useRoute,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

And Router.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import Home from './components/Home.vue'
import LoginPage from './components/Login.vue'


Vue.use(useRoute)



export default new useRoute({
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component: Home },
        { path: '/login', component: LoginPage }
    ]
})
```

App.vue

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <NavBar />

    <div class="auth-wrapper">
      <div class="auth-inner">
        <router-view />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import NavBar from './components/Nav.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    NavBar,

  }
}
</script>

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:400,500,600,700,800');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #1C8EF9 !important;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
label,
.span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

body,
html,
#app,
#root,
.auth-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#app {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-light {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 14px 80px rgba(34, 35, 58, 0.2);
}

.auth-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
}

.auth-inner {
  width: 450px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 14px 80px rgba(34, 35, 58, 0.2);
  padding: 40px 55px 45px 55px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.auth-wrapper .form-control:focus {
  border-color: #167bff;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.auth-wrapper h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.custom-control-label {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.forgot-password,
.forgot-password a {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #7f7d7d;
  margin: 0;
}

.forgot-password a {
  color: #167bff;
}
</style>
```

And for easy finding i am sharing console error
And also i want to share this information that if i write "/login" or "/" it just going to home page,and nothing changing

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?c320:4605 [Vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?c320:4605
vue.runtime.esm.js?c320:4605 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <router-view> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>
```

Comment: I believe that you're using VueRouter 4 which requires Vue 3 - but you are using Vue 2. Revert back to VueRouter 3 and it should work.

Comment: @IVOGELOV actually i am using vue router 3,but it still not working

Comment: Then you should instantiate your router as shown in the [manual](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript) - and not through `useRoute`.